# Linux, assign CPUs to processes

Tags: cpu-usage

I have a process which i'd rather want to run it in real-time, but instead of using a real-time OS or running a real-time linux core (which  is bad with internet speed as i found - maybe i am wrong), i was wondering if it is possible (assuming i have 4 cores) to set all processes to run from CPU 0,1,2 and the specific single process to be run from processor 3 ?

Any ideas/help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It’s very unlikely because if how scheduling works on a regular operating system. If you want *real-time*, regular Linux is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @DanielB my application does not require high-precision, i was able to achieve the required precision by a patched kernel PREEMPT_RT . everything was fine except the network speed, apparently even the network was running in real time, would be nice if everything ran on 3 processors normally, and my process ran on a single process with no others sharing it.

Comment: You could try your luck with [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups).

Comment: @gronostaj sounds promising, but i am not sure how can i configure/work with that to do what i need. i saw also `nice` which might help, but i am not sure if that actually works